# Keyboard shortcut for opening "hyperlink under the caret" in Evernote for Mac

Tags: evernote, evernote-app-notebook

Is there any keyboard shortcut for opening "hyperlink under the caret" in Evernote for Mac?

I often find myself in a need to open the hyperlink (or even note link) under a caret and using the mouse is not comfortable and quite slow for me.

I've found following reference for windows: https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Evernote.html
There is "Open hyperlink under caret (or use Ctrl+Enter)".
Unfortunately, I couldn't find such shortcut for Mac: https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/mac/Evernote.html

Isn't this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Evernote for Mac does not support a keyboard shortcut for opening a link.

However, you could probably make a custom automator action to open a browser from selected text. 
http://blog.fosketts.net/2010/08/09/assign-keyboard-shortcut-applescript-automator-service/